# Scheduling Students and Teachers by Building Dynamic Ranges Using Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeking direction in how to approach this workbook for scheduling students with teachers on essentially a daily basis. The conditionals are making my brain ache and I'd really appreciate some advice. I'd like for us teachers to simply mark several conditions:

**In the Students sheet:**

- Y for "yes" in any columns past H (mandatory). This range will grow horizontally with more testing over time.
- N for "no" in columns C:F (optional). Some students are absent or gone for other activities, and a "N" will omit them from the range. Note that we don't do this on Wednesdays.
- a teacher's initial in col G, to link a student with a particular teacher in the Teachers sheet (optional). Some students will need to be with certain teachers.

**In the Teachers sheet:**

- NA (not available) in col E will omit that teacher's column from being used (the teacher may be absent or in a meeting).

Excel would then loop through each student row and automatically stack each student in a column in the Teachers sheet starting in row 5. For example, Student2 has a "Y" in cell K5 and thus should be placed with a teacher in col C, D or F. The teacher in col E is not available. Another example: Student10 needs to always be with Teacher "J".

**Note: If the teachers' initial is not in col G in the Students sheet, then students can get randomly grouped under any teacher who's assigned to reading, math, or writing.**

Thank you SO much for any direction you could provide.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would look to using the Solver. There are some questions on here about assignment models.

Comment: And what is the resolve is requested teacher is not available?

Comment: Good point Black cat. Then the range would just be limited to teachers who don't have the NA in row 4. Lots of conditions...

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. I will look into it--I've never used it before.